# Difficulty loading Image in Swift with Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, kingfisher

I have a strange problem. I am trying to use Kingfisher in order to load and an cache an Image from Firebase in my app. The problem is that kKingfisher does not download the image. I am using a Placeholder Image that is locally stored and the scroll view displays that Image. If I remove the placeholder part from the command, the app crashes. So I know the Kingfisher function works by at least placing the placeholder Image into the UIImageView but not the image from the URL. Here is the code:

Can you point me to the right direction?

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class Backprogramme: UIViewController {

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBOutlet var BackPScroll: UIScrollView!

    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    var folie1Image = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let folie1URL = URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/backmaster-cdb60.appspot.com/o/Folie1.PNG?alt=media&token=efcb8e93-b817-41f3-a96f-946fd47cf468")!
    folie1Image.kf.setImage(with: folie1URL, placeholder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "first"))

      imageArray = [folie1Image.image!]

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count {     
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.BackPScroll.frame.width, height: self.BackPScroll.frame.height)

            BackPScroll.contentSize.width = BackPScroll.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
            BackPScroll.addSubview(imageView)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Comment: can you not point a breakpoint at the following line imageArray = [folie1Image.image!] and see what the forlie1Image points to?

Comment: folie1Image points to the URL it was given. URL also works ok. Displays the image. I already had a print command to check the variable. I also check the folie1image.image and its equal to nil.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the following statement     folie1Image.kf.setImage(with: folie1URL, placeholder: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "first")), most probably setImage failed to set the image from folie1URL. Can you navigate inside the method to see what's the issue?

Comment: The mwthod is here, I cant seem tonfind anything wrong with it: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/Sources/ImageView%2BKingfisher.swift

Comment: it appears you are passing URL where resource of type ImageResource is needed in the line folie1Image.kf.setImage(with: folie1URL...)

Comment: Thanks for your replies so far, however the README on github for Kingfisher states the following:    https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I think however you have a point. I am going to try  ImageResource(downloadURL: folie1URL, cacheKey: folie1URL) and use this to parse to the kf method. Will report  back when  I get home!

Comment: well...didnt work. still no error but image is not showing. placeholder image however is. can it be that there is a restriction in xcode?

Comment: is it possoble that I am trying to unwrap the image before it is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue , discovered I had this in the log "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection" .

I fixed it by adding **NSAppTransportSecurity** as a Dictionary in the **info.plist** and then I added **Allow Arbitrary Loads** boolean with YES as a value . It worked instantly.
[image]